Task execution failed
After a refactoring of a few modules (moved things around) there is a compilation error:
e: Could not load module <Error module>

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsMyIapKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 54s

e: Could not load module <Error module>
Flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xuse-experimental=kotlin.Experimental

so, as far as I understood the issue is that this flag -Xuse-experimental=kotlin.Experimental is supposed to be used in some module? I see that one of the modules in the app uses this flag in gradle:
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += ["-Xuse-experimental=kotlin.Experimental", '-Xjvm-default=all-compatibility']
}

So, I have added the same to my new module and another one that has been changed, but still this error happening.
How to get an idea of what is wrong? How to debug this issue correctly? Any advice is appreciated.
EDIT
As log states an error happened in Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsMyIapKotlin' is there a way to find this taks in order to find out what is going wrong there?

Does this answer your question? A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

For the compiler flag -Xuse-experimental your error says:
Flag is not supported by this version of the compiler

I therefore suggest you remove it from all build scripts where it is present, rather than add it.
This option was deprecated in v1.5.30. In line with that, I find it only gives a warning when using it with the current (v1.9.23) version of Kotlin, so I presume you are treating warnings as errors for your one or more of your Gradle scripts.

doesn't help:( it says that error happened in Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsMyIapKotlin', is there a way to find this task in order to find out what is going wrong there?

Well, it's a kapt task. If you're using kapt, make sure its version is consistent with the Kotlin version in use (docs)
